# Metrics in spark structured streaming to get the total batch time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

In Spark structured streaming spark by default print metrics, But as per the documentation *triggerExecution* must be the total time spent on execution of a whole batch.

```
triggerExecution = batch_time = (addBatch + getBatch + getEndOffset + queryPlanning  + setOffsetRange + triggerExecution + walCommit)
```

This is not the case, also total batch time is not exactly equal to the *triggerExecution* time.
The total execution time of a batch is somewhat comparable to

```
batch_time = triggerExecution + addBatch
```

Metrics

```
"timestamp" : "2020-10-06T09:45:41.721Z",
  "batchId" : 12609,
  "numInputRows" : 199800,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 651.0624570275969,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 517.4758161639968,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 357041,
    "getBatch" : 0,
    "getEndOffset" : 1,
    "queryPlanning" : 29,
    "setOffsetRange" : 3012,
    "triggerExecution" : 386105,
    "walCommit" : 12949
  }
```

Reference

- https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/query-metrics-apache-spark-structured-streaming/read
- https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/content/spark-sql-streaming-ProgressReporter.html